# VBA Nested Loop

Tags: vba, for-loop

I'm stuck inserting a for loop inside a For function. Essentially, the script is supposed to search for the strings in the array and then paste it in D38 and paste the value of the next string into the next cell by increments of 3 (As seen by the `For x = 38 To 100 Step 3`). The issue I have is that the `Next x` is skipping the next value of the string and the loop gets stuck. I tried inserting the `For x = 38 To 100 Step 3` inside the `Else` statement of the first for loop but it doesn't work. What else can I do to fix this? Thank you!

```
strings = Array("String 1", "String 2")

For Each strng In strings
    strSearch = strng
For x = 38 To 100 Step 3
    Worksheets("Paste Results Here").Activate
    With ActiveSheet.Columns("D:D")
        Set rFind = .Find(strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True)
    If rFind Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox ("There is no " & strSearch)
            Exit Sub
    Else
            rFind.Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Resize(3, 1).Copy
            Worksheets("Data").Activate
            Set rng = Worksheets("Data").Cells(x, 4)
            rng.Activate
            ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlValues
     End If

    End With
Next x
Next strng
```

Comment: it exits the sub as soon as the first false find.  My guess is you do not want the `Exit Sub` line.

Comment: I added that to stop the code once a string is not found. My issue is that currently, the code works by finding the first string then it gets stuck on that string because of the ```Next x``` function happens before the ```Next string``` and the process starts over again and paste the same values every 3 cells.

Comment: flip the loops, then as soon as you find a positive match exit the inner loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you're trying to do, but let me know if it isn't. Get rid of the inner loop all together and only increment x by 3 when the string is found.

```
strings = Array("String 1", "String 2")
x = 38
For Each strng In strings
    strSearch = strng
    Worksheets("Paste Results Here").Activate
    With ActiveSheet.Columns("D:D")
        Set rFind = .Find(strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True)
        If rFind Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox ("There is no " & strSearch)
            Exit Sub
        Else
            rFind.Offset(0, 5).Resize(3, 1).Copy
            Worksheets("Data").Activate
            Set rng = Worksheets("Data").Cells(x, 4)
            rng.PasteSpecial xlValues
            x = x + 3
        End If
    End With
Next strng
```

Comment: Doh! You were right! I didn't need the second For loop after all. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

`Exit Sub` bails out of the procedure scope entirely.

You don't want that - you want to bail out of the inner loop, but keep iterating to perform the next search.

`Exit For` will do that.

```
If rFind Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("There is no " & strSearch)
        Exit For
```

Not clear what your conditions are, but it sounds like you also want to `Exit For` when you *do* have a match. Now, if you bail out of a loop whether or not you've found what you're looking for, reconsider whether you need an inner loop at all.

Or, search for each search-string for each value of x instead of searching for each value of x for every search-string, [as Scott suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58069318/vba-nested-loop/58069428#comment102534631_58069318) ("flip the loops"):

```
For x = 38 To 100 Step 3
    For Each strng In strings

        Set rFind = Range.Find...
        If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
            ...paste special...
        Else
            ...msgbox
        End If

    Next
Next
```

Use `Exit For` to exit a loop body, and `Exit Sub` to exit the procedure completely.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I would like to find strings in the array and copy the three values next to that string and paste it in cell D38 of the "Data" worksheet. I would like to then go to the next string in the array and paste the next three values  in D41 and so forth. I want the ```Exit Sub``` function when a string is not found to exit everything.  My issue right now is that when the first string is found, the loop becomes stuck because the ```Next x``` occurs before ```Next string``` and it cannot go to the next string.

Comment: Yes, hence the suggestion to flip the loops, such that `Next (string)` occurs before `Next (x)` (note the identifiers are superfluous noise that doesn't need to be there - `Next` is the operative word here, any identifier after it only serves to bloat up code)